# Comment rechercher seulement dans les titres de question ? — How to search in questions' titles only?

Tags: support, search

En utilisant le moteur de recherche du site, si je ne m'intéresse qu'aux titres des questions (et non pas aux réponses) qui correspondent à ce que j'ai tapé, que me faudra-t-il inclure dans ce que je tape ? Après avoir inclu `is: question`, j'ai encore obtenu des réponses en tant que résultats.

---

When using this site's search functionality, if I'm only interested in question titles (and not answers) that match what I've typed, what do I need to include in my search query?  When I included `is: question`, I still got back answers as results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour chercher dans les questions seulement, c'est `is:question` sans espace, plus le ou les autres termes de recherche. Exemple : [`is:question orthographe`](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20orthographe) (questions contenant « orthographe »).

Pour chercher uniquement dans les titres, c'est `title:mot`. On peut combiner ce terme avec certains autres, mais pas avec une recherche dans le corps du texte. Exemple : [`title:traduction closed:1`](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Atraduction+closed%3A1) (questions closes dont le titre contient « traduction »).

Pour des recherches vraiment complexes, si vous savez programmer, vous pouvez utiliser l'[API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) pour télécharger un sur-ensemble de ce que vous cherchez et filtrer ensuite localement.

---

To search in questions only, use `is:question` without spaces, and add other terms you are looking for. Example: `is:question orthographe` (questions that include “*orthographe*”).

To search in titles only, use `title:word`. This can be combined with other search terms, but not with search in the body of questions. Example: `title:traduction closed:1` (closed questions whose titles include “*traduction*”).

For very complex searches, if you happen to know programming, you can use the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to download a superset of expected results and filter locally afterwards.